# execute .app, "permission denied"

Tags: macos, installation, osx-snow-leopard

I have some trouble with `.app` files / packets. A good amount of those doesn't do anything when I try to execute those. If I look into the `contents` and try to start the script manually (over the terminal), I receive a "`Permission denied`" message.

That is for instance

```
/Contents/MacOS/Great Installer
```

If I try to execute that => "Permission denied"

If I try to open the whole `.app` by just double-clicking, just nothing happens.

No Problem with `.dmg` files, just with those `.app` things. Using OSX 10.6.8 and I'm logged in with adminstrator rights. Any ideas?

Comment: ls -l the actual executable. Is it set executable?

Comment: @Perry: thanks man. It indeed wasn't, a simple `chmod 775` did the trick. However that can happen ?!.. Thanks again